# quiverで矢印の凡例をつくりたい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

南北、東西の風をあらわすv-windとu-windの風向を表示した矢印で表したコードです。
アスペクト比を固定したまま、風速1m/sを表す矢印を凡例として図の右上あたりに表示したいのですが、どのように処理をおこなえばよいのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```py
U = nc1['uwnd_c'][ip][il][m - 1]
V = nc2['vwnd_c'][ip][il][m - 1]

X_rev = volume_down(array=X, step=2)
Y_rev = volume_down(array=Y, step=2)
U2 = volume_down(array=U1, step=2)
V2 = volume_down(array=V1, step=2)

plt.quiver(X_rev, Y_rev, U2, V2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', width=0.001, scale=0.5, zorder=3, alpha=0.65)

name = "slp_" + ".png"
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig(os.path.join(tmp3, name), format='png', dpi=150)
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

[matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiverkey](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiverkey.html) の仕様と、以下のあたりの記事が参考になるでしょう。

[Basemap Overlay on Contour/Quiver Plot Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33249204/9014308)
[Quiver plot on a map with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47649787/9014308)
[How to set quiverkey length scaling with xy data in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54769275/9014308)
[Matplotlib Quiver plot matching key label color with arrow color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55871552/9014308)
[Advanced quiver and quiverkey functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html)
[Pythonのプロットグラフに風速と風向（U、V）をプロットするにはどうすればよいですか？](https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/10370147)

上記の内容から考えると、以下の行を

```
plt.quiver(X_rev, Y_rev, U2, V2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', width=0.001, scale=0.5, zorder=3, alpha=0.65)
```

以下のように書き換えると出来るのでは？

```
Q = plt.quiver(X_rev, Y_rev, U2, V2, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', width=0.001, scale=0.5, zorder=3, alpha=0.65)
plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 1, r'$1 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E', coordinates='figure')
```

動作確認はしてないので、レイアウトが崩れたりしないようにとか見栄えの良い形はどう？とかについては、仕様や紹介記事のquiverkey()の使い方を参考に、パラメータ数値の調整やオプション追加などしてみてください。